# oracle select based on priority

Tags: sql, oracle, select, operator-precedence

I'm trying to rewrite some old SQL queries that look particularly awful.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to prioritize values in a where statement for order of precedence.  Basically the table contains multiple email_code records per user but I want to prioritize based on what records are preferred.  In this case if the email_code is WORK it should be selected.  But if there is no WORK record then HOME should be selected, and so on.  Here is an example of what I am working with.  There has to be a more graceful way to do this...?

```
select 
    * 
from 
    email m
where
    status_ind='A'
    and decode(email_code, 'WORK',1,
                           'HOME',2,
                           'ALT1',3,
                           'ALT2',4,5) = (select 
                                          min(decode(email_code, 'WORK',1,
                                                                 'HOME',2,
                                                                 'ALT1',3,
                                                                 'ALT2',4,5)) 
                                        from 
                                          email
                                        where 
                                          email_uid = m.email_uid
                                          and status_ind='A');
```

Comment: Are you referring to COALESCE? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm

Comment: I don't think COALESCE works in this situation.  In some cases a record may have all 4 of these codes.  Its more about order of precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT e.*,
          dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY user_id
            ORDER BY CASE email_code
               WHEN 'WORK' THEN 1
               WHEN 'HOME' THEN 2
               WHEN 'ALT1' THEN 3
               WHEN 'ALT2' THEN 4
               ELSE 5
          END ) As priority
   FROM emails e
   WHERE status_ind='A'
)
WHERE priority = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas I had not Oracle here but I think you can use something like this

```
select * from (
    select *,min(decode(email_code, 'WORK',1,
         'HOME',2,'ALT1',3,'ALT2',4,5)) mincode 
         over(partition by (email_uid))
    where status_ind='A'
) where email_code=mincode
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it shall be better to create a lookup table to hold email types and their priorities. And then you can join this lookup table with your mail table. Finally, it will be ok to use one of Oracle analytic functions ( row_number, rank, dense_rank etc ) in order to get the highest priority one.